# Maven : Update depencency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, logging

I am looking to update packets containing vulnerabilities.

When I change the version of one dependency, all the child dependencies of this one are not updated.

For exemple, here is the dependency tree of  the dependency `spring-boot-starter-logging`:

```
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.6.3:compile
|  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.5:compile
|  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.5:compile
|  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.14.1:compile
|  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.14.1:compile
|  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.32:compile
```

But the childs dependencies are not updated as described [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/2.6.3) where `ch.qos.logback:logback-core` is up t 1.2.10.

I tried this :

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.3</version>
            </dependency>
...
        </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

But `spring-boot-starter-logging` have no BOM to add :

```xml
<type>pom</type>
<scope>import</scope>
```

When I modify the `pom.xml`, I use the following command :

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository
```

Thank

Comment: Did you try `mvn clean install`?  Or perhaps another part of the pom is specifying an older version of the ch.qos.logback:logback-* dependencies?

Comment: yes I already tried that.

There is no other place in the pom.xml where I would have specified another version of `ch.qos.logback:logback-`

Answer (score 0):

If child dependencies are not correctly updated a parent pom within your project tree must define the `logback-classic` and  `logback-core` version as 1.2.5 within a `dependencyManagement` section.

```
<dependencyManagement>
...
</dependencyManagement>
```

The `dependencyManagement` section may be useful in a multi-module project to "pin" versions of commonly used artifacts for multiple child dependencies (avoiding to specify their version multiple times).

If you are using a single project pom, move `spring-boot-starter-logging` out of `dependencyManagement` and use `dependencies` directly instead.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have the same problem going through dependency : 
```console
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.6.3:compile
|  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.5:compile
|  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.5:compile
|  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.14.1:compile
|  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.14.1:compile
|  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.32:compile
```

Comment: Try debug mode `mvn -X dependency:tree` and look to find an entry like `[DEBUG] ch.qos.logback:logback-core` with 1.2.5. Also double check which repository is in use? Example `[DEBUG] Repositories (dependencies): [maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/, default, releases+snapshots, blocked), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]/repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]`

Comment: I found one entry `ch.qos.logback:logback-core` with 1.2.5 but still for the same starter-logging package.

Comment: Concerning the repositories, I have :
[DEBUG] Using mirror maven-default-http-blocker (http://0.0.0.0/) for ow2-snapshot (http://repository.ow2.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots)
And others but not the same like you

Comment: Could you upload your debug log for further investigation? (use a pastebin etc.)

Comment: well both `com.ecom.drive0:ecom` and the mysterious `com.XXX.XXX:XXX` poms should be checked.

Comment: The problem does not come from that https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/azemugehad.yaml

Comment: It does. Line 109/110 clearly tell `version managed from 1.2.5` which happens when you are using `dependencyManagement` instead of `dependencies` as explained. Other than that 2.6.4 should really be 2.6.3.